Plural or singular? There is or there are?
In some book I have encountered the following phrase:

There are a number of text conventions used throughout this book.

and a question has arised: whether there should be used the verb is or the verb are. That is whether the phrase should be interpreted as

There is a number ...

or as

There are text conventions ...

Is there a typo or is the phrase correct?

We never use uncontracted singular There is a number of ways to say it, but many people use the contracted form informally, as in There's a number of options on the table. But this is an English Language Learners question.

"Number" is a number-transparent noun in that the number of the whole NP depends on the number of the noun that is complement of the prep "of" (called the 'oblique').  As it happens, "number" takes only plural obliques, so the correct verb-form in your example is plural "are". Note that this applies only to "number" where it has the indefinite article "a".

Excepting, @BillJ, when the number is the main event, as in The number of responses you received is amazing.  And, of course, that contrasts with A number of the responses you received are amazing.

Thanks all for your comments.

@PaulTanenbaum I did say in my comment that "number" is only 'number-transparent' if it has the indefinite article "a", where it indicates an imprecise number, as in the OP’s example. Elsewhere, e.g. with “the,” it indicates a precise number, where the subject NP is singular by virtue of having singular non-transparent "number" as head, as in your first example.
